# Examples of Parallel planes and others.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to draw this but I would like to add an extra mark there by putting some examples of these. They  must be in a 3D cartesian plane. Any help?

1. Three parallel planes
2. Two parallel planes and a third that meets them both
3. Three planes that meet in three lines
4. Three planes that meet in one line
5. Three planes that meet at a single point

Comment: Do you want recommandations on software to use, equations for planes that will work, or ...? And have you actually solved any of the cases yourself?

Comment: I would like to know equations, I am a 10th grade student, and I am taking this University course. I mean, I know exactly how they look like and have the idea. I tried for the parallel but the 3D equations confuse me. the different plane equations...

Comment: Suggestion: you should make the planes meet in the $z=0$ plane, and nowhere else.  That makes things easier to visualize.  For example, in #4, you can make the line of mutual intersection be the $z=x=0$ line.

Comment: All three lines in case 3, can't be in the $z=0$ plane, and parallel planes don't meet at all (in this setting). But $z=0$ can still be used as one of the planes in those cases.

Comment: But I need like a vector equation.

Answer (score -1):

In generalized intercept form, if a plane cuts the intercepts a, b & c with X, Y & Z axes respectively, then the equation of the plane in 3-D is given as follows
$$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$$
where a, b & c are real numbers. For any two planes in 3-D space, the difference either in the sign or in the magnitude of any of these three intercepts a, b & c make them non-parallel to each other while the equal ratio & the same signs of the corresponding intercepts of two planes make then parallel in three dimensional co-ordinate system.

Case 1. If three planes are parallel then the ratio of the corresponding intercepts of three planes must be same hence their equations are written as follows
$$\frac{x}{a_1}+\frac{y}{b_1}+\frac{z}{c_1}=1$$
$$\frac{x}{a_2}+\frac{y}{b_2}+\frac{z}{c_2}=1$$$$\frac{x}{a_3}+\frac{y}{b_3}+\frac{z}{c_3}=1$$
satisfying the following condition
$$a_1:b_1:c_1::a_2:b_2:c_2::a_3:b_3:c_3$$
while the values of intercept a, b & c for each plane are taken as positive

Case 2. If two planes are parallel & third one meets them both then the ratio of the corresponding intercepts of former two (planes) must be same while that of third hence their equations are written as follows
$$\frac{x}{a_1}+\frac{y}{b_1}+\frac{z}{c_1}=1$$
$$\frac{x}{a_2}+\frac{y}{b_2}+\frac{z}{c_2}=1$$$$\frac{x}{a_3}+\frac{y}{b_3}+\frac{z}{c_3}=1$$
satifyng the following condition
$$a_1:b_1:c_1::a_2:b_2:c_2\not=a_3:b_3:c_3$$
while the values of intercept a, b & c for each of first two planes are taken as positive

Case 3: Three planes having equations 
$$\frac{x}{a_1}+\frac{y}{b_1}+\frac{z}{c_1}=1$$
$$\frac{x}{a_2}+\frac{y}{b_2}+\frac{z}{c_2}=1$$$$\frac{x}{a_3}+\frac{y}{b_3}+\frac{z}{c_3}=1$$ will be intersecting at three different lines if 
the corresponding intercepts of all three planes are equal while other are different i.e. $a_1=a_2=a_3$ or $b_1=b_2=b_3$ or $c_1=c_2=c_3$ (while rest are unequal corresponding intercepts (may have different signs) to make the planes non-parallel but to make them meet at a single point on any of X, Y & Z axes)

Case 4: Three planes having equations 
$$\frac{x}{a_1}+\frac{y}{b_1}+\frac{z}{c_1}=1$$
$$\frac{x}{a_2}+\frac{y}{b_2}+\frac{z}{c_2}=1$$$$\frac{x}{a_3}+\frac{y}{b_3}+\frac{z}{c_3}=1$$ will be intersecting at a single straight line if the above three equations satisfy the equation of the line $$\frac{x-x_1}{a}=\frac{y-y_1}{b}=\frac{z-z_1}{c}$$

Case 5: Three planes having equations 
 $$\frac{x}{a_1}+\frac{y}{b_1}+\frac{z}{c_1}=1$$
$$\frac{x}{a_2}+\frac{y}{b_2}+\frac{z}{c_2}=1$$$$\frac{x}{a_3}+\frac{y}{b_3}+\frac{z}{c_3}=1$$ will be intersecting at the single point in the space if the above set of three equations has a unique solution which can be checked out by using determinant method or  "Cramer's Rule".